# Unable to open port 443 in Azure Centos vm's

Tags: linux, centos, azure, virtual-machines

I created a new VM under Centos 7.7 but I’m unable to get the port 443 open..

I created an new Resource group, a new Virtual network/subnet ( both with the default setting) , open ports 22 ,80 and 443 in the Network interface in Inbound port rules.

I have access to the port 22 and can connect through SSH but the port 80 and 443 is still blocked and I can’t understand why…

I deleted and created many new other VM’s and I always have the same behaviour.

I tried also to create new VM’s in different regions and the same issue occurs…

I don’t have any Application security groups.

The weird things is yesterday I created a VM with the exact same settings than the one I applied today and I have access to port 22,80 and 443.

But in that region or other region, if I applied the exact same setting for new VM’s, it doesn’t work…

Firewalld is disabled in Centos by default. ( I still double checked and yes, firewalld is disabled).

I just tried with a Debian O.S and the issue is the same.

What could be the reason?

Edit: if I install openvpn,the port 443 is now open but I don't understand why

Edit :in Network Security Groups, there is no "firewall" tab. But in "settings"/inboud Security rules, port 443 is open.

Also,in "Support + troubleshooting" / "Effective security rules",port 443 is shown as open.

Edit :

```
ss --listening --tcp --numeric
State      Recv-Q Send-Q                                   Local Address:Port                                                  Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      100                                          127.0.0.1:25                                                               *:*
LISTEN     0      128                                                  *:111                                                              *:*
LISTEN     0      128                                                  *:22                                                               *:*
LISTEN     0      100                                              [::1]:25                                                            [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                                               [::]:111                                                           [::]:*
LISTEN     0      128                                               [::]:22                                                            [::]:*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is something listening on port 443/tcp? Try running `ss --listening --tcp --numeric` to verify that

Comment: The outpout  of ss --listening --tcp --numeric is in my question: I edited my post

Comment: you have nothing listening on port 443/tcp, so it's not surprising you cannot reach from outside your cloud provider. Once you install openvpn and configure it to use that port, the service is running, so it listens on that port, and you can reach it. That's why.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Is openvpn absolutely required to listen on 443 port or is there any other software that can be use, just for curiosity?

Comment: Nearly any service can be configured to listen on port 443. Typically this port is used for TLS encrypted HTTP traffic (e.g using Apache HTTPD in CentOS `yum install httpd && systemctl enable httpd && systemctl start httpd`).

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your help, very much appreciated.